# AttributeError: 'PyMongo' object has no attribute 'mydb2'

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

```
from flask import Flask,request,render_template
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app =Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb2"
mongo = PyMongo(app)
db = mongo.mydb2
mycol =db.users
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

its showing:AttributeError: 'PyMongo' object has no attribute 'mydb2'

Answer (score 0):

your MONGO_URI already includes the database (mydb2). according to https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ , you can rewrite your code like this:

```
db = mongo.db
```

[from the doc]

```
db
    The Database if the URI used named a database, and None otherwise.
```

Comment: i have tried this code also but showing the same error..

Comment: Can you add a line to print dir(mongo) right before it throws the error? That’ll give us an idea about the expected API to be used.